# Trouble with ID in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create something interesting in my application. So, I created an UILabel and I want to output new value.

So, my code.

```
   NSString *test = @"13";
   self.UserAge.text = @"Your age is %@", test;
```

But it doesn't work.

In Console-Command Mode I can do it with NSLog(); 
My result is "Your age is %@". But I need to output "Your age is 13". What do I should do with name?
Sorry, if my question is easy for you. I am beginner. :)

Thank you everyone who will answer on my question.

Comment: `UserAge` should be `userAge`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want:

```
NSString *test = @"13";
self.UserAge.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your age is %@", test];
```

Your version is equivalent to:

```
NSString *test = @"13";
self.UserAge.text = test;
```

And I would suggest you use the correct data type, which for an age is an integer:

```
NSUInteger age = 13;
self.UserAge.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your age is %ld", age];
//                   this might be %d, depending on platform ^^^
```

Comment: Thank you. Your first option is true. But the second output only number, and I need with text "Your age is 13". :)

Thank you again!

Comment: @useboot The second version is equivalent to your code, and I am not suggesting you use that version.

Comment: I've been trying to use this version before I asked it here.:)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the following:

```
NSString *test = @"13";
self.UserAge.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your age is %@", test];
```